# How to determine what data visualisation tools are being used on a website

Tags: search-engines

I help maintain a website that is housed in the Squiz Matrix cms. Because we have several Tableau public and MS Power BI reports embedded throughout the website, soon the Power BI reports will be migrated to another data centre server so the embedded links will need to be updated on the website, so I'm needing to determine where Power BI reports are. I've searched for ways to check a website for Power BI reports with no success, so have tried looking for ways to search a whole websites html in order to find the most common trait of the embed code "src="https://app.powerbi.com/view", is there an online tool/method of determining what data vis is being used on a website and where?

Comment: I've revised your original question (in good faith) to potentially open it back up. If you'd like to learn more about _why_ it was closed please review: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic.

Comment: @MikeCiffone Your edit seems like it might broaden the question enough to make it a duplicate of [this question](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/44762/how-can-i-figure-out-what-technologies-a-site-is-built-on).

Comment: @MikeCiffone Your edit still makes the question ask for recommendations   To quote from your edit: "with a tool or API."  I'm inclined to reject your edit because it doesn't greatly improve the question and deviates a bit from the original author's intent.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller "with a tool or api" was included because it doesn't seem like OP is looking to go digging around in source code/dev tools, however, I also agree that adds a recommendation component which I overlooked. It's fine by me if you reject it! I gave it a shot to try and salvage the question since OP is a new user - but even if it _was_ accepted then like Max said have a duplicate.

Comment: @MaximillianLaumeister Yep, and I don't think narrowing it helps at all because unless there's some Power BI specific tool (which I assume OP would have found quickly in their initial search) , the methods I'd use to detect the technologies/data types would be the same for anything else. So definitely duplicate.